# research question about a 'holiday-planning' system

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, research

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

I am looking into implementing a 'holiday-planning' service, which would basically involve users filling up a profile, and the system matching up products & events which are relatively good matches based on their profile.

I would like to ask a question on whether any research exists, best-practices on implementing such a system, and basically anything which one can build upon, rather than re-inventing the wheel.  Not sure under which section of these series of websites this would fall.  My initial guess is Stack Overflow, given that it is programming-related.  I will be using ASP.Net/C# to implement this service.

Comment: Your first stop **must** be search engines rather than SE sites. Unless it's much more precise than what you have, your question is likely to be closed on any SE site.

Comment: @Mat I can elaborate much better on this and make it much more precise - I just didn't here as I was asking more a question of 'where' to put it, rather the actual question.  I've already tried Google, however my main issue is where to start researching such a topic, and even any keywords one would use.  The problem with say Google is that it loads huge amount of irrelevant information, like actual holiday planning services which I do not need, and I'm not aware of the actual keywords one would use to search on this topic.

Comment: @Mat I will post a more precise question on StackOverflow, and then it's up to the moderators to judge if it's a valid question or not, and whether it should be closed - is that ok?

Comment: Even asking where to start might be pushing it a bit. Our Q&A model works much better when questions are more specific and have a correct answer. Discussions don't really work very well.  Instead, break your problem down into smaller, site-sized questions that you can post about. This would involve you doing more research, but the answers you get will be much more helpful for both you as well as future visitors.

Comment: Disclaimer: I hate _where to start_ questions with a passion. You don't know what keywords to search because you haven't tried to implement/design your thing yet and are battling with a completely abstract "service" notion. Get your hands dirty and try to make a mockup (even pen&paper) of what your service will actually do. That'll give you a list of "things" that need implementing, and you can research each of those. If each "thing" is still too abstract, break it down into smaller things.

Comment: As said earlier, I did go through the design of the system and already have a very good idea of how I can implement the system myself from scratch, although not sure if my implementation would be the best way, which I'm sure is not. My main issue is not to re-invent the wheel, and if there is any components / engines / software one can re-use, it would make much more sense.  I didn't include such details in this question because this is not the actual question, but more of a 'question about the question'.

Comment: Karl, there is no **best way** for anything but completely trivial tasks. Unless you're looking for a pre-built system (which you're not), you need to research the individual components. Asking about "where to start a holiday planning system" isn't what you're after if you've already got a design. Ask specific questions about the specific parts, or specific questions about how to make these parts interact.

Comment: answered in: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/165773)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you ask on travel.stackexchange.com how to make such decisions (what is a good way to find events I might be interested in seeing on my holidays?). This will give you some or all of:

- algorithms you might want to implement
- data sources you can later mine (websites of events for example)
- insight into what competition exists and what features they have

(Note that you didn't ask "what algorithms should I implement?" That would be off topic. But an interesting and well-constructed question will attract answers that a careful reader can learn from.)

At that point you have a much more general "matching people to their interests" problem to solve, and some of your design and architecture questions related to it would be a good fit for programmers.stackexchange.com. Not "where do I start" but "this way will be faster and take more space; this way will be smaller but slower, how do I choose which to do?" kind of questions.

And then as you code, you may get errors you don't understand or have trouble understanding an API - those are on topic on stackoverflow of course.Or you may have some holiday-specific, or event-specific questions and head back to travel. It's all good.